# Function plotting in r

Tags: r, statistics

```
x<-seq(-2*pi,2*pi) #range of x
f<-(2*(abs(sin(x)))+(1/2))
f1<-function(x)(2*(abs(sin(x)))+(1/2))

x1=seq(-2*pi,-pi)
g<-2*cos(x1)
gun<- function(y) 2*cos(x1)
curve(gun, from=-2*pi, to=-pi, type='l')
```

So, I want to plot these functions in the same graph but I get an error when I try to plot g:

```
Error in curve(gun, from = -2 * pi, to = -pi, type = "l") : 
'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

I am not sure how to fix this, I've seen people use Vectorize() but it doesn't seem to help.
Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling data stored in your environment in your function. It should be referencing the data that is passed into it.

```
x<-seq(-2*pi,2*pi) #range of x
f<-(2*(abs(sin(x)))+(1/2))
f1<-function(x)(2*(abs(sin(x)))+(1/2))

g<-2*cos(x1)
gun<- function(y) 2*cos(y)
curve(gun, from=-2*pi, to=2*pi, type='l')
```

[image]

to add the second function to the plot you can run this

```
curve(f1, from = -2*pi, to = 2*pi, type = 'l', col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: @AndyPapadopoulos exactly, the curve function is passing it data using the input y so the variable needs to be the same in the function. Otherwise it will search for x1 in the environment, and it found it which is why it wasn't returning an error, but not exactly what you want.

Comment: True, thank you very much for that. Now to merge to curve functions into 1 plot, do I use matplot()?

Comment: @AndyPapadopoulos forgot about that part. I updated the answer with the code

Comment: Thank you very much for that, helped me understand my mistake, appreciate it. :) @kristofersen

Comment: @AndyPapadopoulos np, happy to help :)